# Detect events/features/trend in Time series Data for a particular kind of data

Tags: algorithm, statistics, signal-processing, real-time, feature-detection

[image: DataView]

Background for the data: it is the data from a single variable from a machine like a bulldozer (pressure of the hydraulics, which is responsible for the movement of its bucket), which performs actions like loading its bucket and then moving the vehicle to a place to dump the loaded material and then dumping the material.

I have marked the Load Event (loading the bucket), Haul Event (machine moving to dump), and Dump Event (dumping the load).

So one Load Event, Haul Event and Dump Event constitutes a Complete Cycle. In the image provided I see 12 such cycles.

Problem Statement: Detect the count of such cycles in the data provided, and also eliminate the noise (I have marked Noise in red in the image). Also calculate the time taken by each event: how much time it took for the load event, haul event and dump event? Combining these three gives the complete cycle time.

I tried to detect it using a moving average but it doesn't fit well.

Can anyone suggest a machine learning/ANN/better way which can accurately detect the events?

Observing at the image one can learn that the initial peaks are Load and then Haul and the last spike would be Dump. So, we need to detect peaks based on a dynamic threshold.

Any viable approach to solve this problem is appreciated.